# Find quantity of electricity of two circular faces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

So, there are two circular conductive sheets with quantities of electricity of Q and -Q. If I know that the distance d between them is 0.002 meters and their radius is 0.1m and the voltage between them is 30V, how can I find their quantities of electricity? Here is the image: [image].......I tried using the Gauss's law, but I'm not sure how to actually find Q. Please help me on this.

Comment: Are these parallel plate capacitors? They look axially displaced but maybe that's just your drawing.

Comment: When you say "quantity of electricity" I assume you mean "charge", and that it's a question of language. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of problem, you draw a "Gaussian pill box" - a cylinder with one surface between the plates, the other surface outside. The divergence of the electric field integrated over the area should be related to the total charge inside.

Now you know the voltage and the distance, so you know the electric field in between the plates. And you can assume for this geometry that there is no field outside the plates.

That should be enough to solve the problem - your answer should look a lot like the equation for a parallel plate capacitor (which you can easily Google), and note that there is a very simple relationship between voltage, charge and capacitance:

$$Q = CV$$

That should allow you to check your result.